# data factory linked services common data services

Tags: dynamics-crm, azure-data-factory, common-data-service

i am trying to connect to the common data services by using my Office 365 account and it is not successful. here is the error:

> Unable to Login to Dynamics CRM: Invalid Login Information : An
>   unsecured or incorrectly secured fault was received from the other
>   party. See the inner FaultException for the fault code and detail. An
>   unsecured or incorrectly secured fault was received from the other
>   party. See the inner FaultException for the fault code and detail. =>
>   Authentication FailureUnable to Login to Dynamics CRM Unable to Login
>   to Dynamics CRM The creator of this fault did not specify a Reason.

I can use Power BI common data services connection and successfully connect to the model and pick the entities however it is not successful in data factory!

I have googled thew error and as you can guess there might be whole range of issues but mostly talking about the time difference. I tried to use the on-Prem Runtime to see if it makes any difference but still no hope.

PS: My server is "crm6.dynamics.com"

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I am having the same error.

Answer (score 0):

did you try visiting home.dynamics.com and from there on choose custom app. This shall land you on Dynamics. Also can you visit admin.powerplatform.com and see there atleast 2 env, One as default and other as your CRM. Remember default is not your crm.